# PHP FFMPEG not working when I convert video to mp4

Tags: php, ffmpeg, mp4

I use this code for converting youtube video to mp4.
But its taking very much time.
Please anyone can help me. My code is shown below.

```
'ffmpeg -i "'.$from.'" -ab '.$audio.' -vb '.$video.' -vol '.$volume.' -ac 2 -acodec mp2 -ss '.$start.' -t '.$duration.' "/ebs/dls/mp4/'.$to.'_dl.mp4"'
```

Comment: Use code tags. Question is also more about ffmpeg than about php.

Comment: Yes, re-encoding takes a long time. Don't do it in a response script but rather as a background job.

Comment: Speify a low bit rate for both audio and video codecs. The smaller bit rates are usually faster to encode.  But see other comments - it's not fast = full stop. Use a background process.

Answer (score 2):

*"taking very much time"* is not indicative of a specific problem, or useful in any other way:

1. It only means that the process is taking longer than what you want/expect. What are your requirements with regards to the performance of your application? What is your acceptable latency limit? How many videos do you want to process e.g. per hour?
2. You do realize that converting a video file to another format is a time-consuming process, right? The file has to be decoded and then encoded again, which is computationally intensive. In addition, the overall time is in direct proportion to the length and resolution of the input file. If you expect to convert a 1-hour HD film in a couple of seconds you are probably expecting way too much.